# Failing to add host in Ambari server

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh, ambari

I am using single machine to set up Ambari server, so that I can install Hadoop. A lot of sites were referred to. The error I am getting while registering node is:

```
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2017-07-26 14:50:10

Permission denied (publickey).
SSH command execution finished
host=shubham-r528-r728, exitcode=255
Command end time 2017-07-26 14:50:11

ERROR: Bootstrap of host shubham-r528-r728 fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (255)
ERROR MESSAGE: Permission denied (publickey).

STDOUT: 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lGA5.png)

I have

```
shubham@shubham-R528-R728:~$ hostname -f
shubham-R528-R728
shubham@shubham-R528-R728:~$
```

I follow http://linux-sys-adm.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu-server-14.04-lts-step-by-step/  on my root account to set up ssh key.

Comment: Does the ssh key work when you test it outside Ambari? Is root the default user suggested by ambari? Otherwise using the provided default user may help. -- Also check out": https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/18946/problem-during-ambari-confirm-hosts.html and https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21465/ambari-host-registration-failed-unable-to-install.html

Comment: i didnt test it, i have no idea how to use this , currently i am looking for hadoop cluster management with ambari.thats why need to set up

Comment: And i get this shubham@shubham-R528-R728:~$ ssh shubham-R528-R728
The authenticity of host 'shubham-r528-r728 (127.0.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 2c:f4:4a:ce:5b:7c:5b:fa:2f:52:58:5b:37:ea:8e:1a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/shubham/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: ^ Please add that detail to your question, Shubham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps are required for setting up a cluster with amabari:

1. Setting up passwordless SSH
2. Letting ambari make use of this

The symptoms you see occur in part 2, but judging from the comment the root cause of the problem is actually in part 1.

The good news is that when problems are not hadoop specific, you will see that typically more people will run into them, and post solutions.

I am not sure whether this helps in your case (as you are doing things as root), but a quick search for failing to add the host led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928228/failed-to-add-the-host-to-the-list-of-known-hosts-how-to-debug), which basically indicated that there may be a right issue on the relevant ssh file.

Just thinking out of the box: if your problem is that the host cannot be added to the known hosts file, perhaps you can add it manually somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to [install ambari-agent manually](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.1.0/bk_ambari-administration/content/install_the_ambari_agents_manually.html) on all hosts in the cluster. Adding hosts using this method avoids the need to copy around SSH keys.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu:

1. Install the Ambari Agent on every host in your cluster: `apt-get install ambari-agent`
2. Configure the Ambari Agent by editing the ambari-agent.ini file as shown in the following example: `vi /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini`

ambari-agent.ini:

```
[server]
hostname=<your.ambari.server.hostname>
url_port=8440
secured_url_port=8441
```

3. Start the agent on every host in your cluster: `ambari-agent start`
4. The agent registers with the Server on start.

---

If manual ambari-agent registration is not an option for some reason, and you must use SSH, then you can add the key fingerprint  of the remote host by executing the following command:

```
ssh-keyscan -H shubham-R528-R728 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```